# No boxes coordinates OpenCV::dnn inference GPU

Tags: c++, opencv, deep-learning, yolov8

I am running the example of inference (C++) for YOLOv8 that you can find in the official repository. It works ok on CPU (slow) but it paints the correctly the boxes, no GPU used, it remains at 0%.

When I change it to GPU it doesn't paint the boxes. I can see the GPU running at 25% (It is an NVIDIA 4080) for the time it takes to process the picture.

I began to debug the code and I can see that it detects the same amount of boxes with GPU and CPU, but the coordinates in GPU mode are always 0.

OpenCV is compiled with CUDA and CUDNN support, and i can see that opencv detects my nvidia card.

Any idea why the OpenCV doesnt return the box coordinates on GPU?

Regards

I was expecting the same behaviour in GPU or CPU, just faster on GPU.

Answer (score 1):

After all day searching I found the solution.

https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics/issues/3682

In my case I just need to rollback from OpenCV 4.8 to OpenCV 4.7. Tested and working.

I hope it helps.

Comment: this is the only solution that work for me!